# How can I find the position where the image inside the ImageView starts?

Tags: imageview

I am working on an application related to indoor positioning on Android. I have two imageViews holding the map image and the location marker image. map image can be changed dynamically at runtime. What I want to do is to fit this image to the screen keeping the aspect ratio and determine the position of the location marker relative to the size of the image inside the imageView. Here is my code for this:

```
public void setPointPosition(){

        float xStart = 0, yStart = 0;

        if(imageWidth / imageHeight <= mapImage.getLayoutParams().width / mapImage.getLayoutParams().height){
            xStart = (mapImage.getLayoutParams().width - (mapBeacons.get(0).actualX * (mapImage.getLayoutParams().height / mapBeacons.get(0).actualY))) / 2;
        }else{
            yStart = (mapImage.getLayoutParams().height - (mapBeacons.get(0).actualY * (mapImage.getLayoutParams().width / mapBeacons.get(0).actualX))) / 2;
        }

        pointImage.bringToFront();
        pointImage.setX(x + xStart);
        pointImage.setY(y + yStart);
    }
```

`

imageView xml:

```
<ImageView

        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon" />
```

the problem is that getLayoutParams().width returns -1 when layout_width = 0dp (match constraint). When there is a fixed value such as layout_width = 430dp, it does not fit the image on the screen in different screen sizes.

How can I find where the image starts in the ImageView while fitting the image to the screen?